# Embedded video youtube

Tags: youtube

I wanna learn how you guys can implement an embedded youtube video of personalize dimensions. I searched on Google "how to" and I tried some of the tips, but still not working. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file `index.html`. Open it with your text editor (e.g., Notepad). Add the following to it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My Embeded YouTube video</h1>

<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWPMSSsVdPk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Change `width="1280"` and `height="720"` to the desired number of pixels. Change `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWPMSSsVdPk"` to whatever youtube video you want. For instance, if you'd like to change it to the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohr6O78jGzs

Just switch `bWPMSSsVdPk` to `ohr6O78jGzs` in the `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWPMSSsVdPk"` part, such that `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/ohr6O78jGzs"`. Just note that not all videos are embeddable.

Open `index.html` with a browser. Just drag and drop it into the browser window.

Should do the trick.

Comment: @Andrei It works perfectly fine here: http://i.imgur.com/qjDxiEf.png Please show what you've done so far. Edit your question and add your code. Also, please note that questions to stackoverflow should be novel and of high quality. Saying it just doesn't work, and not showing what you've tried and what research you've done so far is often considered too low effort to merit help.

Comment: sorry for disturbing, i found another solution. Thanks a lot :)